# Add a count field to a django rest framework serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization

I am serializing the built-in django Group model and would like to add a field to the serializer that counts the number of users in the group. I am currently using the following serializer:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'user_set')
```

This returns the group ID and name and an array of users (user IDs) in the group:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Test1",
    "user_set": [
      9
    ]
}
```

What I would like instead as output is something like:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Test1",
    "user_count": 1
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This should work

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'name','user_count')

    def get_user_count(self, obj):
        return obj.user_set.count()
```

This adds a `user_count` field to your serializer whose value is set by `get_user_count`, which will return the length of the `user_set`.

You can find more information on SerializerMethodField here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Just had to change "obj.user_set" to "obj.user_set.all()"

Comment: maybe obj.user_set.count() or something

Comment: This answer is very useful when mongoengine is used and reverse relationships are not available.

Comment: You can remove `self` from parameters and add @staticmethod decorator on your definition. :)

Comment: @Elmux would it change something or would it just be prettier/  more pythonic?

Answer (score 80):

A bit late but short answer. Try this

```
user_count = serializers.IntegerField(
    source='user_set.count', 
    read_only=True
)
```

Comment: Awesome answer . . . . this will also work `user_count = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
    source='user_set.count'
)`

Comment: Is it possible to filter user_set too? something like: `serializers.IntegerField(source='user_set.count', read_only=True, filters={'user_set.x':'y'})`

Comment: not sure. [these](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments) are the available options for a serializer field. i think the best way will be to use [serializers.SerializerMethodField()](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) where you can do any type of custom work including filtering

Comment: Nice answer.One question will it fire separate queries for each object to get count of onetomany relation ?

Comment: @PrashantRajput. i think that depends on how you have initialized your `queryset` or `get_object()` etc with `select_related` or `prefetch_related`. you can take a look [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/1964#issuecomment-59645915). 

But looks like at the moment you cannot specify in serializer field to use `select_related` or `prefetch_related` for source attr. here is an open [issue](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/1977) for this.

[source](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) attribute doc

Answer (score 4):

Everyone's answer looks great. And I would like to contribute another options here - to use `@property` if-and-only-if you can modify the target model.

Assume you can modify the `Group` model.

```
class Group(models.Model):

    @property
    def user_count(self):
        return self.user_set.count
```

Then you can simply add `'user_count'` to `fields` in your serializer.

I'm using this approach but I'm thinking to switch to the serializer approach as other's answer here.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: I'd rather not touch the model at all. It's the API's responsibility to provide extra functionality and fields.

Comment: If the count value is needed by both admin and restful, it would be better to add an extra property to the model - ensure both sides are using same code, as well as dont-repeat-yourself.

Comment: what is user_set ?

Comment: user_set is a property inside Group model.  Just a SET of users belong to `Group`.