# How to count the distinct of model_set in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've looked into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345089/add-a-count-field-to-a-django-rest-framework-serializer), but I think it's different.
Let me explain a bit further. I have a serializer called `DetailTrackSerializer` to serialize my `Track` model, and I've nested a `TaggedSerializer` in `DetailTrackSerializer`.

```
class DetailTrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=120)
    link = serializers.URLField(max_length=120)
    tagged_set = TaggedSerializer(many=True)
    artist = ArtistSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('id', 'artist', 'title', 'link', 'tagged_set',)

class TaggedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = TagSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Tagged
        fields = ('tag',)

class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name',)
```

Currently, this `DetailTrackSerializer` is returning a json like this

```
{
    "tracks": [
        {
            "id": 168,
            "artist": {
                "id": 163,
                "name": "Gob"
            },
            "title": "Face the Ashes",
            "link": "",
            "tagged_set": [
                {
                    "tag": {
                        "id": 1356,
                        "name": "punk rock"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "tag": {
                        "id": 1356,
                        "name": "punk rock"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "tag": {
                        "id": 1356,
                        "name": "punk rock"
                    }
                },
                ...
```

The list goes on, if there are 100 "punk rock" tag in this track, it will shows up 100 times and there may be another tag also not only "punk rock". What I need is something like this

```
{
    "tracks": [
        {
            "id": 168,
            "artist": {
                "id": 163,
                "name": "Gob"
            },
            "title": "Face the Ashes",
            "link": "",
            "tagged_set": [
                {
                    "tag": {
                        "id": 1356,
                        "name": "punk rock"
                    },
                    "frequency": 100,
                },
                {
                    "tag": {
                        "id": 546,
                        "name": "pop"
                    },
                    "frequency": 236,
                },
                ...
```

Each tag only appears once, and has its frequency.
Note: I'm using Django Rest Framework as well

Edit: models.py

```
class Tagged(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
class Track(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through='Tagged', blank=True)
```

Comment: Can I see your model?

Comment: @MohammadAli sure, I've updated the question

Comment: where is frequency field in your model ?

Comment: @HemanthSP there isn't one, this frequency has to be count from the records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through Django's docs about [querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/), this is the solution I came up with

```
class DetailTrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=120)
    link = serializers.URLField(max_length=120)
    tags_frequency = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    artist = ArtistSerializer()

    def get_tags_frequency(self, track):
        tags = track.tags.all()
        return tags.values('id', 'name').annotate(Count('id'))

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('id', 'artist', 'title', 'link', 'tags_frequency',)
```

which will give me json representation like this

```
{
    "tracks": [
        {
            "id": 168,
            "artist": {
                "id": 163,
                "name": "Gob"
            },
            "title": "Face the Ashes",
            "link": "",
            "tags_frequency": [
                {
                    "name": "punk rock",
                    "id": 1356,
                    "id__count": 100
                },
                {
                    "name": "punk",
                    "id": 1357,
                    "id__count": 60
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 169,
            "artist": {
                "id": 164,
                "name": "Jeff And Sheri Easter"
            },
            "title": "The Moon And I (Ordinary Day Album Version)",
            "link": "",
            "tags_frequency": []
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

From your `Tagged`  I understood that there are big chances of **`Data Redundancy`**, that's why your `tagged_set` is showing multiple times.
What I'm trying to say is, **this is not a `Representation Problem` with your serializer**, rather than **it's an `Implementation Problem` with your Models**.
So, `unique_together` attribute will solve the problem, as

```
class Tagged(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('track', 'tag')
```

After changing the models, please do `makemigrations` and `migration`.
**Note**: While doing `migration` you may come acrross `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed` exception. So, delete all entries in the `Tagged` model

Comment: I'm afraid this unique_together is not possible, because multiple user have to be able to tag a `track` with the same `tag` but only once per user. Then, the only option left is `unique_together = ('track', 'tag', 'user')`. I've thought about this before, but I intentionally do not implement it because I need import the data from a dataset which do not have information about which user has tag which track. So, I default the user field to user with id=1

Comment: You said the `user` is same in your *context*, So What is the problem with `unique_together = ('track', 'tag')` ?

Comment: From what I understand, these 2 records won't be possible if using `unique_together = ('track', 'tag')`, "user A, track N, tag J" and "user B, track N, tag J", am I wrong ?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But I didn't understand how that cause problem in your context

Answer (score 0):

Edwin Harly, you have some data overlap between Track, Tag and Tagged model. If you accept, I suggest you remove Tagged model. and if you want to save which user create tag, add user field in Tag model.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

class Track(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through='Tagged', blank=True)
```

Then, you can your serializers like this:

```
class DetailTrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=120)
    link = serializers.URLField(max_length=120)
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)
    artist = ArtistSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('id', 'artist', 'title', 'link', 'tags',)



class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name',)
```